# Can you cancel a bounty and not give it to any of the answers?

Tags: support, bounties

None of the answers are any good, I don't wish to give a bounty. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: 50 bounty is a waste of our time.  Rephrase: your rep.

Comment: @Popular this is probably a better link to pass around: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: @waffles, oh, right, there're specific pages now. Fair enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can let it lapse, or answer it yourself and assign the bounty to you (you will get no points)

Comment: But will he lose any?

Comment: @john bounties are non-redeemable ... once you set it you lost the rep. see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: That's what I thought.  I just wondered if he might lose the rep by setting a bounty, and then regain it by awarding it to himself effectively causing no change at all.

Comment: `bounties are non-redeemable` I assume you meant non-*refundable*.    Yes, it’s been argued many times, and while most people don’t like the idea of bounties evaporating into thin air, it does make at least a little sense. If you post a classified ad, you can pay some money to have it “stickied” or in color or something for a while in order to draw more attention to it. If your ad didn’t work and you didn’t sell/buy what you wanted to, you don’t get a refund. This is the same thing. (On the other hand, even **lawyers** often offer *you-don-pay-anything-if-we-don’t-win-your-case* deals.)