# Is there a way to make the bounty not be automatically awarded to a wrong answer?

Tags: discussion, bounties

First I read [Can you cancel a bounty and not give it to any of the answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69731/can-you-cancel-a-bounty-and-not-give-it-to-any-of-the-answers). Then I had a look to my bounty with my answer, posted after the bounty started, and found no option to give the bounty to myself. I do know, the bounty's gonna be lost, if I give it to myself.

Then I found [Can I not give a bounty to myself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105033/can-i-not-give-a-bounty-to-myself)...which says this feature was disabled.

So is there any way similar to the one described in the first link metioned above which could make the bounty rep be lost, if the OP (and the bounty starter) thinks no answer is worth even half of it?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Is it to make sure that the bounty doesn't get awarded to a "wrong" answer? If so, ask *that* question.

Comment: @ChrisF I've changed my question title in respond

Comment: Down-vote the "wrong" answer. If it doesn't have a score of +2 it won't be awarded the bounty

Comment: @ChrisF, this is the only thing the bounty starter can in the end?

Comment: Yes, other that award it to another answer (which I assume isn't possible)

Comment: @ChrisF thanks a lot, I actually felt, it's something like this about bounties, but wasn't sure...it's always better to ask, I guess:)))

Comment: I think mods have a tool for cancelling active bounties, to be used in such circumstances.

Comment: @ManishEarth I guess answers should be extremly low quality, for moderators to decide to apply it. But I'll remember the opportunity to flag my post, if something. Thanks!!!

Comment: @ManishEarth - nope. There is a tool, but not have an answer you want to award the bounty to is not a valid reason to use it. I put "wrong" in quotes to indicate that the answer might not actually be wrong, but that you didn't want the bounty to be given to it.

Comment: @ChrisF: Ah, thanks :) Wasn't too clear about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The autoaward only happens if the answer has a +2 score. Generally, a wrong answer wouldn't have such a score.

If you're talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13157464/1198729), it has only a +1 score--no need to worry yet. Anyway, it seems that there's at least some work involved in the answer-- what's the problem with the user getting 50 rep for it?

There *is* a tool for cancelling bounties--but it's not really for cases where the OP doesn't feel the answers deserve a bounty.

Comment: Please don't flag for mod attention to cancel a bounty because you don't like the answer. Just deal with it. The rep is lost anyway, they have put some effort into an answer, and if it got a score of more than +2 it was helpful to some. Good for them. Don't explicitly award it perhaps, so they only get half. But other than that I would say "suck it up".

Comment: Yes, right that answer, and the work involved in that answer, IMO, has no attempt to help solve the issue...Never mind)) I just wanted to be sure about how I can influence the flow of the bounty, if something. I've got the answer. Thank you for that.